# Concatenate 2 lists within list

Tags: r

Say I have n lists within a list. An example with n = 2 is L3. I want a way to rbind elements within the n lists without knowing what n is. L4 gives me what I want, but I need to specify how many lists are within L3.

```
L1 <- list(c(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3), c(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3))
L2 <- list(c(a = 2, b = 3, c = 4), c(a = 2, b = 3, c = 4))
L3 <- list(L1, L2)
L4 <- Map(rbind, L3[[1]], L3[[2]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option with `do.call` and `Map`

```
do.call(Map, c(f = rbind, L3))
```

-output

```
#[[1]]
#     a b c
#[1,] 1 2 3
#[2,] 2 3 4

#[[2]]
#     a b c
#[1,] 1 2 3
#[2,] 2 3 4
```